# How to simulate production workloads on a dummy database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds, performance, performance-testing

We are planning to enable Multi AZ on our production database which uses Amazon RDS as a managed service. Our Database is using SQL Server 2012 standard version.

Before enabling that, I wanted to simulate our production workload on a dummy database to check how the read write latency are getting affected after making the dummy database as Multi AZ.

Whats the best way to do the above ?

Comment: Generally enabling the multiaz will create a bit latency in both read and write operations. SQL servers are using database.mirroring (Brent (who answered this question) already wrote a blog about this, since you are a sql server person so just take a look ). But yeah you must do a benchmark to compare the latency.

Comment: One option is to use SQL Agent and ostress: [Simulating Workload With ostress And Agent Jobs](https://brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/simulating-workload-ostress-agent-jobs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Brent’s idea, nice and simple and will give you an indication of what you need. Here are also options to replicate the actual real workload:

- record it in production and replay it using SQL distributed replay
- manually capture select statements using profiler (may be tricky)
- involve more advanced performances testing tools such as Hammer DB, SQLStress
- write your own queries and in SSMS run them in different tabs with GO x, where x is the number of iterations (yes SSMS can do this) to simulate concurrent workload (although that’s more or less what SQLStress would do)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The fastest, easiest way is to rebuild an index on a large table.

That pushes a lot of write activity through, and it’s consistent, easily repeatable, and easily timed.

It’s not your workload (or anything near it) but helps you get a fast idea of the overhead right away.

Comment: Hi @Brent, To compare the overhead before and after enabling Multi AZ , Are you suggesting that I pickup an index which has a lot of write activity and then measure the time taken while rebuilding index for that specific table both before and after ? Can i use the same index to rebuild twice for before and after Multi AZ?

Comment: When you rebuild an index, it doesn't matter if it's frequently written or not - an index rebuild builds a new copy of the index from scratch.

Comment: Hi @Brent, which approach shall i take for rebuilding indexes ? 1. Using SSMS, rebuild task or via script ? If its through script , can you share some useful links.

Comment: ALTER INDEX ALL ON dbo.MyTableName REBUILD;